# Passing arguments to an entry point python script using argparser

Tags: python, arguments, argparse, setup.py, sys

I am looking to pass a user entered arguments from the command line to an entry point for a python script. Thus  far I have tried to used argparse to pass the arguments  from the command line to the test.py script.  When I try to pass the arguments they are not recognised and I recieve the following error.

> load_entry_point('thesaurus==0.1', 'console_scripts', 'thesaurus')()
>   TypeError: find_synonym() missing 1 required positional argument: 'argv'

I have looked at other examples on here but have not been able to get any of the solutions to work.

```
def main(argv):
    if argv is None:
        argv = sys.argv

    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Enter string')
    parser.add_argument('string', type=str, help='Enter word or words', nargs='*')
    args = parser.parse_args(argv[1:])
    print(args)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    sys.exit(main(sys.argv))
```

My setup.py script entry point looks like the following

```
setup(entry_points={'console_scripts': ['test=test_folder.main:main']})
```

What I expect to happen is similar to when I run python main.py main foo. Which will successfully print out hello when it is passes to the function.

Comment: If you are using argparse, why are you using sys.argv?

Comment: @OldWinterton, using `argv` like this gives some flexibility when testing `main`.  This script runs fine when called in a conventional way.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

So it works now when I remove the the arguments from the function.

```
 def main():          
        parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Enter string')
        parser.add_argument('string', type=str, help='Enter word or words', nargs='*')
        args = parser.parse_args()
        print(args.string)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

I believe that it might work with the sys.arv  used in the first example, as my actual problem was that when I re-downloaded this script from GitHub using.

> pip install git+ URL

The script was not updating so the error persisted, This required deleting all the files related to the GitHub repository and re-installing it using the same pip command.

Comment: I provided a full working example based on this answer in a blog post for anyone interested

https://hughesadam87.medium.com/dead-simple-pytest-and-argparse-d1dbb6affbc3

Answer (score 3):

To get the best of both worlds, `main()` should accept argv (which makes it easier to test, as you [observed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61565153/passing-arguments-to-an-entry-point-python-script-using-argparser#comment108907055_61565153)). However, you need a default to use it as an entrypoint so it can be invoked with no args. That would look like this:

```
def main(argv=sys.argv):
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Enter string')
    parser.add_argument('string', type=str, help='Enter word or words', nargs='*')
    args = parser.parse_args(argv[1:])
    print(args)
```

Now it is testable and you can still use it as an entrypoint.